# Say I have 5 text strings. How do I find the 2 that are most "different" from the rest?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP.

Say I have 5 strings:

```
"The quick brown fox"
"The sly brown fox"
"The sly brown chicken"
"Totally different text here"
"Not like the others"
```

and I want to find the 2 that are most "different" from the rest. I'd like to be able to expand it to 1000 text strings and getting the, say, 300 most "different".

Any ideas where to start?

**EDIT**

How to define "different" is up for discussion!

*** EDIT 2 ***

We defined "different" as different according to the PHP `similar_text` function. But there could be other definitions. The real problems is how to compare all the text strings. Jean suggested counting the totals, and this is the hacked version of Phillipe's code that does so:

```
$strings = array(
    "The quick brown fox",
    "The sly brown fox",
    "The sly brown chicken",
    "Totally different text here",
    "Not like the others"
);

$n = 3;
$sim = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($strings); $i++) {

    $total = 0;

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($strings); $j++) {

        if($strings[$i] != $strings[$j]) {

            $sim_val = similar_text($strings[$i], $strings[$j]);
            $total += $sim_val;
            $sim[$strings[$i]][] = array(
                "sim" => $sim_val,
                "w1" => $strings[$i],
                "w2" => $strings[$j]
            );

        }
    }

    $sim[$strings[$i]]['total'] = $total;

}

uasort($sim, function($w1, $w2) {
    return $w1["total"] > $w2["total"];
});

$sim = array_keys($sim);
$sim = array_slice($sim,0,$n);
```

That returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Not like the others
    [1] => Totally different text here
    [2] => The quick brown fox
)
```

which does seem like the correct answer. Thanks to all (apart from those who downvoted the question. Booo to you ;-)

EDIT 3 ***

OK, so I've been testing this with my 1000 strings. They each have around 500 unique words, and a `strlen` of around 14000. So ... to get this running quickly we can immediately forget about `similar_text` 'cos as pointed out, it's slow. I wrote a quick `compare_words' function:

```
function same_words($text1,$text2) {

    $words_1 = array_unique(explode(" ",$text1));
    $words_2 = array_flip(array_unique(explode(" ",$text2)));       

    foreach($words_1 AS $word) {
        if($words_2[$word]) {
            $count++;   
        }
    }

    return $count;

}
```

but that's too slow too.

Comment: What on Earth do you mean by "different"?

Comment: Define "different". Character counts? Verbal sounds? Meanings?

Comment: I think he means Different words

Comment: similar_text() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Part of the problems is getting a definition of different, which is why I put it in inverted commas. Different words is a good place to start, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `similar_text()` function and get the lowest percentages.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is a little bit brute force and test every word with the other words, store the similarity (i.e. based on similar_text) and then order the result by similarity

```
$strings = array(
    "The quick brown fox",
    "The sly brown fox",
    "The sly brown chicken",
    "Totally different text here",
    "Not like the others"
);

$n = 5;
$sim = array();
$sum = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($strings); $i++) {
    $t = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($strings); $j++) {
        if ($j != $i) {
            $t += similar_text($strings[$i], $strings[$j]);
        }
    }

    $avg = $t / (count($strings) - 1);
    $sim[] = array(
        "sim" => $avg,
        "word" => $strings[$i]
    );

    $sum += $avg;
}

$avg = $sum / count($strings);
usort($sim, function($w1, $w2) use ($avg) {
    return abs($w1["sim"] - $avg) < abs($w2["sim"] - $avg);
});

for ($i = 0; $i < $n && $i < count($sim); $i++) {
    echo $sim[$i]['word'] . "<br />";
}
```

But you have keep in mind, that this approach is not very fast and runs in `O(n^2 * m^3 + n log n)`

Instead of `similar_text` you could also use levenshtein which performs quite better and results in something like `O(n^2*m^2 + n log n)` (where m is the max length of the input strings)

Comment: Thanks very much, great reply. I thought we might just have to "brute force" it

Comment: Just wondering how to expand this to the 3 most different .. or the 300 most different out of 1000 strings.

Comment: That gives 
'The sly brown fox' and 'Not like the others'
'The sly brown chicken' and 'Not like the others'
'The quick brown fox' and 'Not like the others'
which are the 3 strings with the most amount of difference between each other, not the 3 strings most different from all the others. Am currently working on Jean's suggestion to compare all strings and have a look at the total accumulated score.

Comment: ok.. i just updated the code..

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a thought:
Define what you call being different. Identify many kind of difference and attribute them a score. For instance :

- Identical strings : 0
- Some common words, in the same order: score depends on the extent of the order and the number of common words.
- Some common words, but non in the same order
- Some words having a common set of letters in the same order (e.g. virtual and virtually), etc...

The higher the score, the higher the difference between the strings for the investigated criteria.

Then compute a "difference" score for two  strings. The highest the score, the most different they are.

This kind of approach is commonly used when needing to take a decision based on multiple different parameters. It is how some anti-spam software identify spam. Except they compute a score to determine how similar an e-mail is to a spam.

The issue is: it is always about comparison. So you can compare two strings together, but not one string to the rest. So to identify the two most different strings, you will need to resort to some average system… and select those whose score is the further away from the average.

Comment: Or you could just opt not to re-invent the wheel and use the similar_text() function suggested by jimjimmy1995.

Comment: Interesting discussion of how to define "different", many thanks. Yes, the problem I have mentally when trying to conceptualise this is that I can find out how similar two text strings are, but not one string with the rest. I will think about your average idea.

Comment: Or you could also compare each string to all the others and add the scores. The strings with the highest accumulated score is the one that is the most different to all others.

Comment: Thanks Jean, good idea. Will post resultant code...